# How to render conditional jsx using ternary operator in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to use ternary operator for conditional rendering of jsx using react and javascript.

below is my code,

```
const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <Child 
            isChecked={true}
            isMany={true}
        />
    );
};

const Child = (props) => {
    const name=defaultTo(props.optionName, 'name');
    return (
        {props.isMany
            ? `${props.getValue().length} ${name}${
                props.getValue().length > 1 ? 's' : ''
            } selected`
            : props.getValue()[0].label
        }
    );
}
```

the above code works and it returns output like "2 names selected" or "1 name selected" based on getValue length. here Child component is reusable and isChecked prop is optional. it may or maynot be passed as prop to this Child component.

Now if the isChecked prop is true, i want to display output like "2 selected" or "1 selected" which depends on getValue length.

how can i modify the above code to do so.
could someone help me with this. thanks.

**EDIT:**
below is what i have tried.

```
const Child = (props) => {
    const name= props.isChecked ?
                defaultTo(props.optionName, '') 
                : defaultTo(props.optionName, 'name');
    return (
        {props.isMany
            ? `${props.getValue().length} ${name}${
                (props.getValue().length > 1 && !isChecked) ? 's' : ''
            } selected`
            : props.getValue()[0].label
        }
    );
}
```

this kind of works but still displays that 's' if more than one count so the output is like below

1 selected
2 s selected
3 s selected
....

Comment: Can you provide more details about what changes when `isChecked` is true? Only the returned string of the Child component changes?

Comment: yes only the return string changes

Comment: So, if `isChecked` is true, the name property is not redered, instead only `props.getValue().length + " selected"`?

Comment: @Kleiton Pereira: yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do much of the work before the `return`, something along these lines:

```
const Child = (props) => {
    const {isChecked, isMany, optionName} = props;
    const value = props.getValue();
    const {length} = value;
    const nameDisplay = isMany && `${defaultTo(optionName, "name")}${length === 1 ? "" : "s"}`;

    return (
        isMany
            ? isChecked
                ? `${length} selected`
                : `${length} ${nameDisplay}`
            : value[0].label;
    );
};
```

I should note that just adding an `s` works for `name`, but doesn't work for many other nouns in English (`bus` for instance, or `mouse`). Making plurals in English is, sadly, fairly complicated in practice. Rather than accepting just `optionName`, you might consider accepting something that includes both the singular and the plural.

---

Side note: `? :` is **a** ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands, like a binary operator accepts two operands and a unary operator accepts one), and it's JavaScript's only ternary operator at the moment, but that could change. Its proper name is the *conditional operator*.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another ternary operator.

```
const Child = (props) => {
    const name=defaultTo(props.optionName, 'name');
    return (
        {props.isChecked ? 
            props.getValue().length + " selected" : 
            (props.isMany
                ? `${props.getValue().length} ${name}${
                    props.getValue().length > 1 ? 's' : ''
                } selected`
                : props.getValue()[0].label)
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks. this string should be displayed also when isMany is true. so meaning when isChecked and isMany to be true

Comment: @stackuser - I think we'd be better able to help if you listed all four combinations of `isMany` and `isChecked` and what outputs you want for (say) `optionName = "example"` for all four of them.